# How to remove optional from a string value in swift?

Tags: swift, option-type

In the code I'm not able to remove optional from the value inside the `lbltotalamount`.
The value in `lblTotalAmount` is not removing its optional value from it.
Why? The value in `grandtotal` gets optional removed but when I assign it to a label it returns an optional value again.
The `lblTottalAmount` is getting an optional value. I want to remove it.

```
if success == false {
    var  grandtotal: Any?  = value["total"]
    if grandtotal != nil {
        print("O!O!O!O/\(grandtotal!)")
        grandtotal = String(describing: grandtotal)
        self.lblTotalAmount.text = ([grandtotal]) as! String  // (here I am not able to remove optional)
    }
```

Comment: What type is `grandtotal` supposed to be?

Comment: grandtotal should be string @v

Comment: Then why do you create a string from a string and force cast the string to string? By the way casting `[String]` to `String` doesn't work anyway. Isn't `grandtotal` rather a numeric value, `Int` or `Double`?

Comment: grandtotal could be numeric or float but I want it in string , the code grandtotal = String(describing: grandtotal) I was just trying another approach for make my code work ,,, I want a the result in a string , self.lblTotalAmount.text = ([grandtotal]) as! String from this line ,sir

Comment: this also getting me a optional :----->if grandtotal != nil{
               print("O!O!O!O/\(grandtotal!)")
                    var  g: String?
                    g = String(describing: grandtotal)
                    //grandtotal = String(describing: grandtotal)
                    self.lblTotalAmount.text = g as! String
                }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the line

```
grandtotal = String(describing: grandtotal)
```

You check for `nil` but you don't unwrap the value so it's still an optional.
And you are misusing `String(describing`. Never use it for types which can be converted to `String` with an `init` method.

Use always conditional downcast

```
if success == false {
   if let grandtotal = value["total"] as? Double {
       self.lblTotalAmount.text = String(grandtotal)
   }
}
```